# React Native passing Component/Object property to OnPress function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, draggable

Just started learning React Native and running into some basic issues. 
I am using the React-native-draggable component, and I would like to use the position of the  element to update the state of my current scene.

```html
<Draggable renderColor='white' offsetX={0} renderSize={48} reverse={false} pressDragRelease={PASS X,Y POSITION TO A FUNCTION HERE?}>
```

For the life of me I can not get this to work; I really just want to get the x and y position of the Draggable element that is released, and use that in this.setState( ... ). I've tried binding, but really I'm a complete beginner and don't even know where to look right now. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. By taking a quick look at the module source code, you can see [here](https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable/blob/3c73084f2cf570d49e5240daca123f1574024f5f/Draggable.js#L79) that the `pressDragRelease` function is called without any parameters.

```
onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
    if(pressDragRelease)
        pressDragRelease();
[...]
```

What we want here is to get x and y from `gestureState`.
We can pass `onPanResponderRelease` params to `pressDragRelease`:

```
onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
    if(pressDragRelease)
        pressDragRelease(e, gestureState);
[...]
```

Feel free to fork and submit a pull request!

**Update**

I've made a PR here: https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable/pull/7

**Update 2**

The PR has been merged and a new version of the module published to npm!

`npm install react-native-draggable@1.0.8`

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you so so much! From StackOvervlow question to merged module update in < 5 hours... amazing. Thanks again!

Comment: @kytwb I tried same thing but, I am not getting this X and Y, I am just getting only touch point, not X and Y. could you please help me for the same.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD What version of the module are you using? Can you share a link that reproduces?